# How to Resolve NSMutableArray may not respond to ObjectForKey

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

How to resolve the following type of warning?

- NSMutableArray may not respond to objectForKey.
- UISwitch may not respond to setAlternateColors:

My code for switch is:

```
[mySwitch setAlternateColors:YES];
```

and For Array is:

```
NSMutableArray *tmp1 = [sortedIndexedArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSMutableArray *tmpDict2 = [tmp1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *companyNameString =  [tmpDict2 objectForKey:@"firstname"];
NSString *flName = [tmpDict2 objectForKey:@"title"];
[searchCustomCell setDataForEvent1:companyNameString venue:flName];
```

Answer (score 4):

NSMutableArray doesn't respond to `-objectForKey:`. Your variable name "tmpDict2" is misleading; an array is not a dictionary.

Array store an ordered list of objects; dictionaries store an unordered mapping of keys to values (objects). Thus `-objectForKey:` only applies to a NSDictionary.

Perhaps you want this? I can't really be sure based on what you've provided...

```
NSDictionary *tmp1 = [sortedIndexedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSDictionary *tmpDict2 = [tmp1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

As for your switch, perhaps you made a custom subclass of UISwitch which responds to `-setAlternateColors:`? In that case, try using `[(MyUISwitchSubclass *)mySwitch setAlternateColors:YES]` or just make the variable `mySwitch` have type `MyUISwitchSubclass *`. On the other hand, if this is a private method, you should avoid using it in your app.

All in all, I can't really tell exactly what you're trying to do unless you provide some more information and context.

Comment: setAlternateColors is actually a private API message (not a custom subclass), so he definitely shouldn't be using this. :)

Answer (score 1):

`objectForKey` is an instance method of `NSDictionary`. You are using it on `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 1):

Try by this code...

```
NSMutableArray *tmp1 = [sortedIndexedArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

NSDictionary *tmpDict2 = [tmp1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *companyNameString =  [tmpDict2 objectForKey:@"firstname"];

NSString *flName = [tmpDict2 objectForKey:@"title"];

[searchCustomCell setDataForEvent1:companyNameString venue:flName];
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is complaining for [UISwitch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html) because that object doesn't contain a setAlternateColors message. setAlternateColors is actually part of a private API, so if you use this message, your app will be rejected by Apple.

As the other answers have pointed out objectForKey is a message on [NSDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html), not [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

`NSMutableArray` doesn't have `objectForKey` method. Use `NSMutableDictionary`.